# How to limit the slides that are part of a "dropped slide"?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I discovered that within a presentation it is possible to drag and drop slides on slides. This allows, in presentation mode, to jump to the dropped slide with a fancy animation (it reminds me of Prezi).

**My question: is it possible to limit the range of slides that are shown after such a click?**

What I have now is a jump to a place in my presentation and when I continue clicking I eventually go through the whole presentation. Since I would like to use the drop functionality to address a subset of my presentation, I would ideally have the following workflow

- in presentation mode, I click on a "dropped" slide
- I present several slides that are part of a group
- when I arrive at the last slide from that group I get sent back to the page with the "dropped slide".

This would effectively allow the presentation to be split "by topics" and address all of them with an intermediate trip back to the main slide that regroups them all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a "Section" in the left drawer (the one with all slides in miniature), and drop that section on the main slide.

The show will be limited to the slides in the section.